# My server can't connect to anything through 443

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, firewall, ufw

I tried to connect to paypal, github and stripe from my server and every connection attempt ended with a "connection timed out". I use ufw as my firewall I have the default incoming rule is deny and the default outgoing is allow. I have already tried to add the ip's of stripe to ufw and its still failing. Ask me anything I will try to provide more information about the problem I am just tired and I want this fixed ty in advance.

UPDATE:

I am using php with correct lib for paypal and stipe. For github I am using wget.

This is the output from wget:

```bsh
--2022-04-28 22:26:51--  https://github.com/xx/gx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/xx
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.3
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2022-04-28 22:27:24--  (try: 2)  https://github.com/xx/gx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/xx
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2022-04-28 22:27:57--  (try: 3)  https://github.com/xx/gx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/xx
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2022-04-28 22:28:32--  (try: 4)  https://github.com/xx/gx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/xx
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2022-04-28 22:29:08--  (try: 5)  https://github.com/xx/gx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/xx
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-04-28 22:29:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I have just noticed that after a few tries wget can successfully connect... . But for php thats not true. So I am thinking about that this might be an issue with ufw or iptables?

Comment: This is an ubuntu server but I can access websites through port 80. But not through 443.

Comment: --2022-04-28 22:27:57--  (try: 3)  https://github.com/xx/xx/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta/cxx
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Comment: Please add your clarifications [directly in the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1405368/edit). If you are using python or bash script, please add the script output and errors by copying from the server terminal and pasting directly in the question. Format the pasted output as `code` by using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution to your question and provided an answer. Please accept your answer as the correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the iptables configuration somehow it conflicted with the docker configuration.

I used these commands to reset iptables:

```bsh
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```